# subview z-position above all views in window

Tags: ios, quartz-core

I don't think this would be possible but I'm hoping there's a work-around someone has found. I have a view we'll call `VIEW0` and another called `VIEW1`.

The `zPositon` of `VIEW0` is `zPosition = 1;` the `VIEW1` is `Position = 0` so it's below `VIEW0`.

In `VIEW1` I have some subviews and I'd like to have one of those subviews be at a higher `zPosition` than `VIEW0` so `VIEW0`'s shadow will not be casted on the particular subview, but it will on all other subviews.

I have tried setting the subview's `zPosition = 2` but that doesn't seem to place it above the `VIEW0`.

**I kind of expected this because they are subviews but does anyone have any suggestions to place a subview from `VIEW1` above `VIEW0`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing the parent of the subview as and when required. The subview object remains the same, but it gets a different parent & position, that's all.

```
[subViewObj removeFromSuperview];
```

and

```
[superViewObj addSubview:subViewObj];
```

Then set the position of `subViewObj` like this:

```
subViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(xStart, yStart, width, height);
```

Comment: i had a segment control in the header of a UICollectionView. I tried using frame.zPosition to keep the segment control on top but was not able click the buttons. Then i used ```headerView.bringSubviewToFront(headerView.controlSegment)``` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the z order, move the subviews that you want to be above VIEW1 to be childs of VIEW1 instead of VIEW0

Since VIEW1 is above VIEW0 then all the subviews of VIEW0 will be bellow any subview of VIEW1

Comment: Right, but it's like folder tabs so it's going to constantly switch which subview is "above". Is there no other way than to pull the subview from it's superview?

Comment: You could play around with the views and add them both to the same superview then using     [theSuperView bringSubviewToFront:VIEW0 or VIEW1];